# Poco::ObjectPool with c++ example

Tags: c++, poco

How do I use the [`Poco::ObjectPool`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ObjectPool.html) class in my c++ program ? Can anyone please delineate this with an example since I am using Poco libraries for the first time.
Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is pretty clear on this. Actually, all I wrote below I deducted from the docs, I've never used Poco myself... but here goes.

---

Let's assume you have a `class Foo`. For some reason you don't want to create a new one every time you need it. Perhaps it is expensive to create. Perhaps it marshals some important resource. You want to *pool* it, take an object from the pool, and put it back into the pool when you're done with it.

You create an `Poco::ObjectPool` for `Foo` objects, giving its starting capacity (number of objects initially created) and peak capacity.

```
Poco::ObjectPool< Foo > pool( 10, 20 );
```

You can now "borrow" objects from the pool. Note that the function can return `nullptr` if the peak capacity is reached.

```
Foo * f = pool.borrowObject();
```

...and return it to the pool when done.

```
pool.returnObject( f );
```

You can provide a policy class to `ObjectPool` to customize its behaviour, the interface being defined by [`PoolableObjectFactory`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.PoolableObjectFactory.html). This class handles how objects are created, activated, validated (to check if they can be reused or need to be destroyed), deactivated, and destroyed (if they cannot be reused, or the pool gets destroyed).

```
struct FooFactory
{
    Foo * createObject() { return new Foo( 42 ); }
    void activateObject( Foo * p ) { p.init(); }
    bool validateObject( Foo * p ) { return true; }
    void deactivateObject( Foo * p ) { p.deinit(); }
    void destroyObject( Foo * p ) { delete p; }
};

Poco::ObjectPool< Foo, Foo *, FooFactory > pool;
```